# Array of char in C + accessing each char

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, struct, char

I need to input n lines with 1 "string"(array of char) each. Then I want to store them in a Word struct and print each one. I need to access first and last char of each "string".

These strings always have the q letter after each char(except the last one).
Example: Hello -> Hqeqlqlqo

**THE MOST IMPORTANT THING, I also need to call a function that receives the "string" and then takes the 'q' off and adds each char to this new struct WordModified, so I can print them all in the end**

So, my question is: How do I access words of both structs char by char? and how do I build my function to exclude the 'q's and append continuously the letters of the words in the WordModified struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1100


typedef struct {
  char name[1101];
} WordReceived;

typedef struct {
  char name[1101];
} WordModified;


int main(void)
{
  //char input[1101];
  int nrlines, i;

  scanf("Number of lines %d\n", &nrlines);
  WordReceived words[nrlines];
  WordModified wordsMod[nrlines];

  for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
  {
    printf("String\n");
    scanf("%s\n", words[i].name);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
  {
    printf("word %d: %s\n", i+1, words[i].name);
    printf("First char: %s\n",  words[i].name[0]);
    printf("Last char: %s\n",  words[i].name[n-1]);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
  {
    printf("word %d: %s\n", i+1, wordsMod[i].name);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: I just edited it, it's in the end

Comment: Why do you need two identical types with diferent type names? And why does a `struct` with a single `char[]` member need to be a `struct` anyway? It looks as though you are making things harder than they need to be. In answer to *"How do I access words of both structs char by char?"*: by writing functions that take `char *` type.

Comment: `void copyodd(char *dst, const char *src) { while(*src) { *dst = *src; dst++; src++; if (*src) src++; } *dst = 0; }`

Comment: If you need to print a string without even chars. Print the string from zero till less then length with a step of two.

Comment: words[i].name[n-1], where 'n' variable is declared?

Answer (score 1):

The function that takes of 'q' character is quite simple. Keep in mind that i haven't handle the case the word include 'q' character, you can practice on that.

I modified a little your code, you can see my comments.

I don't understand why you want to access the first and last character of each word.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1100 //What is for?

void CleanWord(char *word, char* mod_word);

typedef struct {
  char name[1101];
} WordReceived;

typedef struct {
  char name[1101];
} WordModified;


int main(void)
{
  //char input[1101];
  int nrlines, i;

  printf("Number of lines: \n");
  scanf(" %d", &nrlines);
  WordReceived words[nrlines];
  WordModified wordsMod[nrlines];

  memset(words, 0, sizeof(words));      //Initialize the struct
  memset(words, 0, sizeof(wordsMod));   //Initialize the struct

  for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
  {
    printf("String\n");
    scanf(" %s", words[i].name);
  }


  for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
  {
    CleanWord(words[i].name, wordsMod[i].name);

    printf("word %d: %s\n", i+1, words[i].name);
    printf("First char: %c\n",  words[i].name[0]);      //your code has %s formating but the variable is signle character

    int n = strlen(words[i].name);  //store the length of string
    printf("Last char: %c\n",  words[i].name[n-1]);
  }

   for (i = 0; i < nrlines; ++i)
   {
    printf("word %d: %s\n", i+1, wordsMod[i].name);
   }

  return 0;
}

/*  This function remove the char 'q' from the 'word' and store the result to 'mod_word'*/
void CleanWord(char* word, char* mod_word)
{
    int i,j = 0;
    int word_size = strlen(word);

    for(i = 0; i < word_size; i++)
    {
        if(word[i] != 'q')
            mod_word[j++] = word[i];
    }
}
```